# why do I get access violation run time error?

Tags: c, visual-c++, struct, access-violation

I have this structure

```
typedef struct fpinfo
{
    unsigned long chunk_offset;
    unsigned long chunk_length;
    unsigned char *fing_print;
}fpinfo;

typedef struct Hash_Entry {
    struct Hash_Entry *next;  /* Link entries within same bucket. */
    unsigned namehash;        /* hash value of key */
    struct fpinfo fp;
} Hash_Entry;
```

and the following line of code to extract the 10 msb from the fing_print array

```
unsigned int h;
h = (he.fp.fing_print[0] << 2 | (he.fp.fing_print[1] & 0xC0) >> 6) & 0x3FF;
```

Here is how I initialized the he data member by reading contents from a file

```
while(fscanf(rd,"%ul,%ul,%X",&test_st.fp.chunk_offset,&test_st.fp.chunk_length,&test_st.fp.fing_print) !=EOF)
{   
    ....
}
```

vc 2010 gives the error:

**Unhandled exception at 0x013217f8 in htable.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.**

what is wrong with it?

Comment: You are trying to read a pointer value from a file.  That's not going to work.  You'll need to read a string.  And make sure that test_st.fp.fing_print is initialized with malloc() before you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that `he.fp.fing_print` has not been initialized, so your process crashes when trying to access its elements. To verify, print out the value of the pointer, or examine it in the debugger.

**edit** There are two problems with the `fscanf()` code:

1. It's not totally clear what the intent is, but `%X` together with `&test_st.fp.fing_print` *overwrites the pointer*;
2. You don't appear to allocate memory for `test_st.fp.fing_print`.

Comment: I am trying to read chunk offset information from a file and then this offset information will be used to calculate the chunks finger print and after i have to put this final information in a hash table. but before i do all that i am just trying to read offsets from the file and put them in to the hash table

Comment: he.fp.fing_print is a pointer. Where do you initialized it to point to some storage ? There's is _a lot_ of code missing for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

possible reason could be that test_st is not initialized and you are using it to initialize fp.

Comment: It would be great if you could put little more code specially the part where you have declared test_st.